# What is a DD Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>*In the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463), a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

If a word conforms to a special rule, we call it a DD Word™.
Use the examples below to find the rule.

$$
\def\Pad{\P{0.0}}  \def\Title{\textbf{ DD }}
\def\S#1#2{\Space{#1}{20px}{#2px}}\def\P#1{\V{#1em}}\ \def\V#1{\S{#1}{9}}
\def\T{\Title\textbf{Words}^™\Pad}\def\NT{\Pad\textbf{Not}\T\ }\displaystyle
\smash{\lower{29px}\bbox[yellow]{\phantom{\rlap{rubio.2017.02.04}\S{6px}{0}
\begin{array}{cc}\Pad\T&\NT\\\end{array}}}}\atop\def\V#1{\S{#1}{5}}
\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline\Pad\T&\NT\\\hline
\text{JAMJAR}&\text{HONEYPOT}\\\hline
\text{NOSTRIL}&\text{SINUS}\\\hline
\text{GASOLINE}&\text{PETROLEUM}\\\hline
\text{JASPER}&\text{TOPAZ}\\\hline
\text{ENDNOTE}&\text{INDEX}\\\hline
\text{PONDER}&\text{PERUSE}\\\hline
\text{TRAMFUL}&\text{BEWILDER}\\\hline
\end{array}$$

What is a DD Word™?

**Hint 1:**

> Time for a hint!

Comment: rot13(V gubhtug vg jnf N vf 1, O vf 2 rgp naq gur fhz vf bqq sbe QQ jbeqf, ohg gung qbrfa'g tnfbyvar naq crgebyrhz ner gur jebat jnl ebhaq sbe gung naq cbaqre qbrfa'g svg.)

Comment: rot13(Vg'f abg gur ahzrevpny inyhrf bs gur ahzoref nqqrq gb rdhny QQ be 44 orpnhfr wnzwne nqqf hc gb 53)

Comment: rot13(V'z abg fher vs V fubhyq tb qbja gur Qhatrbaf naq Qentbaf be Qhaxva Qbahgf enoovg ubyr )

Comment: @GrumpyLlama59 Lrf, bqq nqqvgvbaf (53, 107, 69) ner QQ, rkprcg gur cnggrea oernxf sbe tnfbyvar, crgebyrhz, naq cbaqre (juvpu nqq gb 82, 125, naq 75 erfcrpgviryl)

Comment: @GrumpyLlama59 Qrsvavgryl qbahgf.

Comment: Guvf bar qbrfa'g arrq nal xabjyrqtr zber nepnar guna n cerfpubby/xvaqretnegra rqhpngvba!

Comment: Ab cynpr sbe zr urer gura :C

Comment: Vf vg gbb rneyl sbe n uvag?

Comment: Vg ernyyl vf n uvag, V cebzvfr!

Comment: Fhz bs yrggref pna'g qrgrezvar vg orpnhfr obgu n QQ jbeq (TNFBYVAR) naq n aba-QQ jbeq (FVAHF) unir gur fnzr fhz (82)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A 'DD' Word is one which:

> Contains a 3-letter sequence made of the initials of 3 consecutive months of the year, either forwards or backwards.

Since:

> J**AMJ**AR contains AMJ (April, May, June)
>  **NOS**TRIL contains NOS (November, October, September)
>  G**ASO**LINE contains ASO (August, September, October)
>  **JAS**PER contains JAS (July, August, September)
>  EN**DNO**TE contains DNO (December, November, October)
>  P**OND**ER contains OND (October, November, December)
>  TR**AMF**UL contains AMF (April, March, February)
>
>  The counterexamples contain no such sequences.

Regarding the name:

> 'DD' is an abbreviation of sorts for '**d**o**d**eca-' (the Greek prefix meaning 'twelve') or '**d**uo**d**ecimal' (base 12) - both with connotations to 12, the number of months in a year.

Comment: Very good! But not quite right on the reason for the name - I'm counting on you to think about it a bit more!

Comment: @jacksonh Thanks - will update if I can think of anything else for the title...

Comment: You are basically correct. The DD stands for (qhbqrpvzny) but I hadn't even thought about the other angle!